# UItableView Section Header View with Xib Error - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I try to implement Section Header with Xib File. I create a Xib View and attend UITableViewHeaderFooterView to this view . When I run the App , it gives me error without any description. Where is the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EventViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventViewCell")
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "EventCellSectionHeader", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "EventCellSectionHeader")


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "EventCellSectionHeader") as! EventCellSectionHeader
    cell.headerName.text = "aa"
    return cell
}

class EventCellSectionHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet var headerName: UILabel!  
}
```

**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

Comment: Could you share the full error message? There should be more above the one you gave. From `Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSUncaughtException` (note the uppercase at "Terminating" + "NSUncaughtException" vs "NSException") to the one you gave.

Comment: This is all. Just write libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException and redirect to AppDelegate file

Comment: Check the identifier name in storyboard for EventCellSectionHeader cell.

Comment: I use xib. Any place to write the identifier name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Xcode 10 SWIFT 4**

implement your viewForHeaderInSection as below:

```
//EventCellHeader is the name of your xib file. (EventCellHeader.xib)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("EventCellHeader", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! EventCellSectionHeader
        header.headerName.text = "aa"

        return header

    }
```

I tested it: (if you need more help let me know to send you the whole project)

[image]

Comment: Which type of your xib file ? UIview or what

Comment: It is Table View Cell. remove the default view.

Comment: And you select UITableViewHeaderFooterView when create swift file rigth?

Comment: right. the whole class: import UIKit
class EventCellSectionHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    @IBOutlet var headerName: UILabel!

    
}

Comment: I tried before that implement UITableViewCell and import class name but doesnt recognize the name. Also now it doesnt recognize. But tap enter after typing all name , it recognize . Why dont recognize first ?

Comment: Im not sure that I got your question,, It think if you clean and build your project then try it again, it works.